# How to increase vertical spacing between entries when using glossaries long style?

Tags: spacing, glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package with long style. However I don't want the entries to be so tight one to another.

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{customlong}{
    \glossarystyle{long}
    % I use this to prevent a different vertical spacing from x2 to y than from x1 to x2
    \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{x1}{name={x1},description={first term}}
\glsadd{x1}
\newglossaryentry{x2}{name={x2},description={second term}}
\glsadd{x2}
\newglossaryentry{y}{name={y},description={third term}}
\glsadd{y}

\begin{document}
test document
\newpage
\printglossary[type=main,style=customlong]
\end{document}
```

How can I increase the vertical space between entries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `long` style uses the `longtable` environment and therefore is *"governed by the same parameters as that environment"* (manual, p. 75). So the following should work (put it immediately before `\printglossaries`):

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}% default is 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer from lockstep should do the trick. If you want to see how the styles are defined, have a look in the glossaries folder in your tex-tree.

Looking at a few styles it becomes fairly obvious how to write your own style or how to change certain settings.