# how to have equal spacing in acronym list?

Tags: spacing, glossaries

I have an acronym list using  `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=super, nonumberlist]` which looks like the following however there is no space between ML and MPC as seen from the below picture:

[image]

Is there a way to have equal spacing for all?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{ml}{ML}{Machine Learning}
\newacronym{rl}{RL}{Reinforcement Learning}
\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically erasable programmable read-only memory}
\newacronym{lfd}{LfD}{Learning from Demonstration}
\newacronym{mpc}{MPC}{Model Predictice Control}
\newacronym{pearl}{PEARL}{Probabilistic embeddings for actor-critic RL}
\newacronym{ffnn}{FFNN}{Feed forward neural networks}
\newacronym{bo}{BO}{Bayesian Optimization}
\newacronym{mdp}{MDP}{Markov decision process}
\newacronym{pomdp}{POMDP}{Partial observable markov decision process}

\makeglossaries
\glsaddall

\begin{document}
   
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=super, nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal document that creates a list of acronyms (like in your image) that we can use to test? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: Assuming you use either `glossaries` or `glossaries-extra`: Add `nogroupskip` to the corresponding package options to change the behaviour for all glossaries in your document or add it to the options of the `\printglossary` command to change the bahaviour for this glossary only.

Comment: We don't have `setup.tex`, which probably defines `\acronymtype`. So, drop the `\input` and supply whatever packages may be included in there, as well as `\acronymtype`.

Comment: in the setup.tex there is only    ' \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}'
which seemed related to it otherwise it's a rather long tex file.

Comment: @leandriis the nogroupskip leaves no space between the acronyms however, right?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13203/134144 should also help in your case.

Comment: @Azerila: Note, for future reference, how I've changed your proposed code so that users can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Elements like `\makeglossaries` and `\glsaddall` should be included, no `\input{setup}` that the audience doesn't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nogroupskip` removes the vertical space between entries with different first letters. `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}` adds space between all entries (works because the `super` style is based on `supertabular`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries


    \newacronym{ml}{ML}{Machine Learning}
    \newacronym{rl}{RL}{Reinforcement Learning}
    \newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically erasable programmable  read-only memory}
    \newacronym{lfd}{LfD}{Learning from Demonstration}
    \newacronym{mpc}{MPC}{Model Predictice Control}
    \newacronym{pearl}{PEARL}{Probabilistic embeddings for actor-critic RL}
    \newacronym{ffnn}{FFNN}{Feed forward neural networks}
    \newacronym{bo}{BO}{Bayesian Optimization}
    \newacronym{mdp}{MDP}{Markov decision process}
    \newacronym{pomdp}{POMDP}{Partial observable markov decision process}


\begin{document}
   \glsaddall
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=super,  nonumberlist, nogroupskip] .

\end{document}
```